# c++ 2 Dimensional Lists

Tags: list, class, c++14

I have a list that hold an array of lists.

I have 2 object types "Flight" and "People" The other one is "Management". I created a list that holds a list of people for each Flight object made. I'm trying to make a  list of lists that holds lists of people assigned to each Flight.

But I can only add 1 list to the list of list at location 0. Anything beyond that is a segmentation fault.

This is my Flight Class;

```
class Flight {
 public:
  int maxPeople;
  int currentPos = -1;
  int flightNo;
  People list[50]; // list of people
  public:
  Passenger *list;
  Flight();
  Flight(int maxPassenger, int flightNo);
  void addPeople(Passenger passenger);
};

class Management {
 public:
 const int maxFlights=20;
 public:
 Management();
 addFlight(Flight flight);
 };
```

This is my implementation of the prototypes:

```
//Global Variables
int currentPos1=-1; //
Flight *list2[20]; //list of list

//Constructor
Flight::Flight(int maxPeople2, int flightNo2) {
maxPeople = maxPeople2;
list = new People[maxPassenger]; //List means List of Passengers
flightNo = flightNo2;  

Management::Management() {};

//Addflight
 void Management::addFlight(Flight flight) {
    currentPos1++;
    *list2[currentPos1] = flight;
}

//Main
int main(void) {
Flight f1 (25, 333);
Flight f2 (25, 444);
a.addFlight(f1); // works
a.addFlight(f2); //Segfault
}
```

I am incrementing the currentPos1 everytime I add. And the list of lists (*list[20]) has 20 spots assigned. I can't figure out why it'll try to access a location out of that 20 that doesn't exist and causing segmentation fault. 
Any Help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't initialize or allocate storage for any of the pointers in `list2` anywhere. It's random that the first call to `addFlight()` doesn't segfault. This code

```
*list2[currentPos1]
```

ends up dereferencing a random memory location. If you change it to this:

```
list2[currentPos1] = &flight;
```

Well that's about as bad, because `flight` is a function parameter that's going to go away as soon as `addFlight()` returns.

Why are you using pointers and native arrays? Don't do that. Use `std::vector`.
Change `list2` to

```
std::vector< Flight > list2;
```

and in `addFlight()`

```
list2[currentPos1] = flight;
```

Comment: Thankyou. We weren't allowed to use vectors, but you did point me to the right Direction. Allocating locations solved it

    list[currentPos] = new int[maxPeople]; //Allocating location for list[20][this]

Comment: I really, really wish instructors would not teach the C based subset of C++ first. It's teaching you all kinds of bad habits. You should be well versed in using `std::vector` and the other standard containers long before you ever directly use dynamic memory.

Answer (score -1):

i changed function `addFlight()` in `Management` as follows and it worked(atleast in my complier which didnt have complete code)

```
list2[currentPos1]=& flight;
```

which origiinally was

```
*list2[currentPos1]=flight;
```

Comment: You're taking the address of a function parameter. That's going to lead to Undefined Behavior and eventually segfaults.

Comment: yeah , thanks for correction didnt pay attention to it. Another method is he(OP) can pass f1 and f2's address  themselves instead

Comment: NVM he got his ans